# Loading bar in c without mess up other outputs

Tags: c, output, loading

I need to make a loading bar like the one in the apt packet manager (image)

[image]

I found a [cool library](https://github.com/doches/progressbar) that implements this, the problem though is that since the progress bar is printed, all text above the loading bar (for example in the image, "Processing triggers for...") is not printed out.

How can I have both the loading bar and the information printed on the screen?

my actual code is this:

```
int main(void){
  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1) {
  char *newline = strchr(line, '\n');
  if (newline)
    *newline = 0;
  puts("");
  currline++;
  progressBar(currline, lines);
 }
}

void progressBar(size_t count, size_t lines){
  progressbar *progress = progressbar_new("Loading",lines); // function provided b the linked library (It initialize the progress bar so takes the name and the number of lines)
  for (size_t i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    progressbar_inc(progress); // provided by the library (it increments progressbar of a single step and call progressbar_update() that print the value by calling progressbar_draw()
  progressbar_finish(progress); // just free all allocated memory and print a newline
}
```

If you want to have a more detailed look to cited functions see [here.](https://gist.github.com/HeroS3c/c323cb344ff136219a2292ecc3eee18a)

Comment: learn about ncurses . It is not possible without escape terminal commands.

Comment: @0___________ I had never heard of it. thank you very much, I'll watch some tutorials about it! :)